# Find non-matching pairs in 2 dataframes and make new missing dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two **uneven** dataframes that have all the same variables except for a pair of ID values that vary from one to the other.

For example one of the dataframes, `df1`, looks like this:

```
Name     Name ID     State     Gen ID      Unit ID
Nikki    9           AZ        1-1         1
Nikki    9           AZ        1-2         2
Nikki    9           AZ        1-3         3
Mondip   101         NY        1A          1A
Mondip   101         NY        1B          1B
James    11          CA        12-1        12
James    11          CA        13-1        13
Sandra   88          NJ        1           1
.
.
.
```

The other dataframe `df2` looks like this:

```
Name         Name ID     State     Unit ID
Monte        97          PA        4-1         
Monte        97          PA        4-2         
Nikki Ltd    9           AZ        1        
Nikki Ltd    9           AZ        2        
Mondip       101         NY        1A         
Mondip       101         NY        1B         
James        11          CA        12-1          
James        11          CA        13-1          
.
.
.
```

As you can see the `Gen ID` column and the `Unit ID` column are somehow connected. Sometimes the `Unit ID` in `df2` can be either the `Gen ID` or the `Unit ID` in `df1`.

What I want to do is to create a new dataframe or list of each set of `Name`, `Name ID`, and `State` that **does not** match `df1` and `df2`. Sometimes the name matches slightly `Nikki` and `Nikki Ltd` so I need to take care of this using the `Name ID`.

For example the new dataframe output `df_missing` would be:

```
Name         Name ID     State     Gen ID      Unit ID
Monte        97          PA                    4-1         
Monte        97          PA                    4-2 
Sandra       88          NJ        1           1
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: [Datacompy PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/datacompy/) might be your answer...  I've never used it, let me know if you try it and if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that you can identify names that are close enough then the first step would be to replace instances of 'Nikki LTD' with 'Nikki'. Once you do that its a simple matter to identify the names that are not mutual to each dataframe. These names are

```
 merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
 s1 = set(df1['Name'].unique())
 s2 = set(df2['Name'].unique())
 # read as every in s1 thats not in s2 and everyone in s2 thats not in s1
 mutually_distinct_names = list((s1 - s2).union(s2 - s1)) 
 missing_df = merged_df[merged_df['Name'].isin(muutally_distinct_names)]
```